# Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work to solve Problem 8 of Project Euler?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve Project [Euler Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8). I'm still quite new to C# so I like to use simple tasks and functions which is why the code is quite long. If I try and find the four adjacent digits that give the highest products it works, but when I try to find the 13 it doesn't work.
string lO is the long number. lO means long one and sO means short one.

```
//Problem 8
            string lO = 
            string sO = "";
            int length = lO.Length;
            int uno = 0;
            int dos = 0;
            int tre = 0;
            int fou = 0;
            int fiv = 0;
            int six = 0;
            int sev = 0;
            int eig = 0;
            int nin = 0;
            int ten = 0;
            int ele = 0;
            int twe = 0;
            int thi = 0;
            long big = 0;
            long total = 0;
            int sub = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                sub = length - i;
                if (sub > 13)
                {
                    sO = lO.Substring(i, 13);
                }
                else
                {
                    sO = lO.Substring(i, sub);
                }
                if (sO.Length >= 13)
                {
                    uno = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(0, 1));
                    dos = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(1, 1));
                    tre = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(2, 1));
                    fou = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(3, 1));
                    fiv = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(4, 1));
                    six = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(5, 1));
                    sev = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(6, 1));
                    eig = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(7, 1));
                    nin = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(8, 1));
                    ten = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(9, 1));
                    ele = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(10, 1));
                    twe = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(11, 1));
                    thi = Convert.ToInt32(sO.Substring(12));
                }
                total = uno * dos * tre * fou * fiv * six * sev * eig * nin * ten * ele * twe * thi;
                //Console.WriteLine("Total: " + total);
                if (total > big)
                {
                    big = total;
                    Console.WriteLine("New biggest is " + big);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's not working? What results do you get?

Comment: @nicomp as in it doesn't work at finding the correct answer. The code itself runs but doesn't give the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line

```
total = uno * dos * tre * fou * fiv * six * sev * eig * nin * ten * ele * twe * thi;
```

since all these variables are of type `int`, multiplying them causes integer overflows and you don't get the correct result.

Use this:

```
total = (long)uno * (long)dos * (long)tre * (long)fou * (long)fiv * (long)six * (long)sev * (long)eig * (long)nin * (long)ten * (long)ele * (long)twe * (long)thi;
```

Or declare them as long in the first place.

Note: Tested on euler, and the result is correct.

Comment: @YoungCompScientist please do not forget to mark as answer if this helped

Comment: You only need to cast the first number to `long`; the rest will be converted automatically. It will save you some typing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Instead of multiple declarations use array i.e. `int[] selected = new int[13];`
2. Rather than taking substrings everytime, convert it to character array using `ToCharArray()`. This would significantly reduce the length of your program.
3. Use `string lo = new string();` and `string so = new string();`
   After doing these changes you can simply use nested for loops to solve the above program.

P.S.
If you need detailed solution please type in a comment to this answer.